# Galerkin’s Method for hyperbolic PDEs: proving convergence without using compactness

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis

Lawrence Evan's PDE book prove the existence of solution to the following problem where $L$ is an elliptic operator:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt} = -Lu+f,\\
u|_{t=0} = u_0,\\
u|_{\partial U} = 0
\end{cases}
$$
on $U\times [0, T]$ via Galerkin’s method. That is, finding an orthonormal basis $\{\varphi_i\},$ and expand $f = \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i\varphi_i,$ and solve the problem in $\text{span}_{i\leq N} \{\varphi_i\}$ for $f$ being the partial sum $\sum^{N}_{i=1} f_i \varphi_i.$ We get a sequence of solutions $u_N.$ Now prove that $u_N$ is bounded in $H_0^1$ and take a weakly convergent subsequence.

My question is - in practice, if we implement this procedure as an algorithm, we expect $u_N \to u$ in $H^1(U\times [0,T]).$ Under what situation does this convergence hold? Is it more restrictive than extracting a weakly convergent subsequence?